# how to constrain the number of clients a TcpListener can accept?

Tags: c#, tcplistener

is there a way to limit the number of clients a tcpListener can accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Count them and dont accept() if you have too many?

Comment: You might wanna accept and then send a packet explaining that the server is full then disconnect, instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can count it in your event handler

```
class Server()
{
  private AutoResetEvent connectionWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

public void Start()
  {
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5555);
    listener.Start();

```
while(true)
{
  IAsyncResult result =  tcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(HandleAsyncConnection, tcpListener);
  connectionWaitHandle.WaitOne(); //Wait until a client has begun handling an event
}
```

}

private void HandleAsyncConnection(IAsyncResult result)
  {
    TcpListener listener = (TcpListener)result.AsyncState;
    TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(result);
    connectionWaitHandle.Set(); //Inform the main thread this connection is now handled

```
//... Use your TcpClient here

client.Close();
```

}
}